# CakePHP and Google+ sign-in

Tags: php, cakephp, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

Has anyone implemented the Google+ sign-in (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) into CakePHP? Apologies for the broad question but I've done a lot of searching and cannot find any tutorials to implement this.

I tried following Google's steps in the link above but don't even know where I'm meant to be installing/using the PHP API and all sites I've found that mention Google PHP API appear to reference old naming schemes/files, presumably from before Google+ days.

I'd rather not implement someone's plugin or component but rather write the controller/model/view code myself using as near to raw code from Google's site as possible. Any pointers would be nice.

Comment: The question *is* broad and pointless because if you don't want to use anything else than your own code you'll have to write it. Read the documentation provided by Google for the API and read the CakePHP book about how to implement custom Authentication adapters.

Comment: As for where to install the PHP API, put it in the app/vendors folder, see the section about vendor files in the cookbook --  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, maybe it was too ambitious. I've settled with Hybridauth which so far seems to work very well. I did actually get the PHP API partly working by using [this trick](http://britg.com/2008/07/07/using-the-zend-framework-in-cakephp/) that was written for including the Zend framework. However the "set" method clashes with the inbuilt Cake one.